# How to join strings with delimeter, that joined strings in inner level in java8 functional style

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have  `Map<String, Set<String>> myMap;` with structure:

```
{
     "key1" : ["val1","val2","val3"]
     "key2" : ["val4","val5","val6"]
     "key3" : ["val7","val8"]
}
```

I can join every value with key with `Collectors.joining`:

`val1 key1 val2 key1 val3`
`val4 key2 val5 key2 val6`
`val7 key3 val8`

but globally I need also combine all values in one string:

```
"val1 key1 val2 key1 val3 key2 val4 key2 val5 key2 val6 key3 val7 key3 val8"
                           ^                             ^
```

where values joined by keys from right value.

Yes, I can achive this in imperative way, but i ask how I can achive this with stream api.

Comment: Are you working on a `NavigableMap` and `SortedSet`?

Comment: Post your imperative code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to `flatMap` twice and build a pipeline of key-value Strings:

```
String s = myMap.entrySet().stream().flatMap(
                 e -> e.getValue().stream().flatMap(val -> Stream.of(e.getKey(), val))
           ).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(s);
```

Will give you:

> key1 val1 key1 val2 key1 val3 key2 val4 key2 val5 key2 val6 key3 val7 key3 val8

The first key String has to be skipped to get your expected output.

```
String s = myMap.entrySet().stream().flatMap(
                 e -> e.getValue().stream().flatMap(val -> Stream.of(e.getKey(), val))
           ).skip(1).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(s);
```

> val1 key1 val2 key1 val3 key2 val4 key2 val5 key2 val6 key3 val7 key3 val8

Comment: It's an elegant solution, but it doesn't meet the requirements. Take a look at the expected outcome in the question.

Comment: Excellent, very elegant, thanks. I did not expect that stream api might so powerfull :)

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be emphasized that this request only makes sense if there is a defined encounter order, which doesn’t apply to the ordinary `HashMap` and `HashSet`.

For maps and sets with a stable order, e.g. `LinkedHashMap`, `TreeMap` and their `Set` counterparts, it would be great if we could use something like:

```
String s=myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(
         ()->new StringJoiner(" "+e.getKey()+" "),StringJoiner::add, StringJoiner::merge))
    .collect(()->new StringJoiner(""), StringJoiner::merge, StringJoiner::merge)
    .toString();
```

But it doesn’t work because `StringJoiner::merge` will use the separator of the *left* `StringJoiner` rather than the *right* one.

Since this behavior is not configurable, we need our own variant of a `StringJoiner`:

```
final class RightHandJoiner {
    String separator;
    StringBuilder content;

    public RightHandJoiner(String sep) {
        separator = sep;
    }
    public RightHandJoiner add(CharSequence next) {
        if(content==null) content=new StringBuilder(next);
        else content.append(separator).append(next);
        return this;
    }
    public RightHandJoiner merge(RightHandJoiner next) {
        if(next.content!=null) {
            if(content==null) {
                content=new StringBuilder(next.content);
                separator=next.separator;
            }
            else content.append(next.separator).append(next.content);
        }
        return this;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return content==null? "": content.toString();
    }
}
```

This is intentionally simplified to just serve your task, e.g. it doesn’t support non-empty prefix and suffix strings. Replacing `StringJoiner` with this class, you’ll get a working solution:

```
String s=myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .collect(() -> new RightHandJoiner(" "+e.getKey()+" "),
                 RightHandJoiner::add, RightHandJoiner::merge))
    .collect(()->new RightHandJoiner(""), RightHandJoiner::merge, RightHandJoiner::merge)
    .toString();
```